# Apache mod_wsgi flask crashes after about a minute

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I have an Amazon EC2 server running Apache 2.4. I am running one website on there using Python and regular CGI, and then another virtual host using mod_wsgi and an index.wsgi script. When I use a default WSGI callable class object script in my wsgi file, it works fine. However, if I use a WSGI-compatible framework like Flask or Bottle, it loads and works perfectly for about a minute, and then suddenly gives an error 503 ON BOTH OF MY SITES. Even if I change my script back to the default, this error persists for about 5 minutes and then it starts working again. I am using mod_wsgi with the usual daemon mode. Please help. I am using RedHat Linux, Apache 2.4, Python 2.7, and the latest flask and mod_wsgi.

EDIT: Here's my site-specific apache .conf file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ihave.nolife.lol
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/ihave/index.wsgi
    WSGIDaemonProcess ihave user=apache group=apache processes=1 threads=5
    <Directory /var/www/ihave>
            Require all granted
            WSGIProcessGroup ihave
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}      
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/www/html/ihave/errorlog
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog /var/www/html/ihave/requests combined
```

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information. But at a guess it is because you are using some third party Python packages which use a C extension module which will not work in sub interpreters. Read the following and set that directive. Also recommended that you make sure you are using daemon mode and not embedded mode.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#python-simplified-gil-state-api

Comment: Thank you, I had already been using the WSGIApplicationGroup directive, I have updated to show my entire apache config file for that site.

Comment: Change ``debug`` for ``LogLevel`` down to ``info``. Look at the main Apache error log (not the virtual host one), for information about when mod_wsgi is restarting processes and why. What details does that show?

Comment: No info is given, here is the content of the log file after about a minute of running the flask application with mod_wsgi, at which point apache crashes. `[Sun Nov 13 02:05:41.358099 2016] [:info] [pid 9495] mod_wsgi (pid=9495): Starting process 'ihave' with uid=48, gid=48 and threads=1.
[Sun Nov 13 02:05:41.358578 2016] [:info] [pid 9495] mod_wsgi (pid=9495): Initializing Python.[Sun Nov 13 02:05:41.408785 2016] [:info] [pid 9497] mod_wsgi (pid=9497): Attach interpreter ''.`

Comment: Apache crashing is very different to a 503 occurring. What error message was in the virtual host log file. A 503 coming from mod_wsgi should log a reason why.

Comment: no error was specifically denoted, but `[Sun Nov 13 03:36:36.734344 2016] [:info] [pid 10604] [remote 10.0.0.37:62951] mod_wsgi (pid=10604, process='ihave', application=''): Loading WSGI script '/var/www/ihave/index.wsgi'.` was the only line relevant to that occurence.

Comment: Have you enabled Flask debug or logging of internal exceptions by Flask? If there is nothing in Apache error logs, there is a possibility the 503 is coming from Flask.

Comment: You know what, thank you for your help, but I think I will just take a different approach to this.